# MailKit SMTP and IMAP read receipts

Tags: vb.net, mailkit, exchange-online

I have a few questions about return receipts using Exchange Online.

If I send an SMTP message with

```
vEmail.Headers(HeaderId.DispositionNotificationTo) = SenderEmail
```

It then sends the return receipt request when the user opens it (in this instance it's me using Domino/Notes)

When that read message is downloaded from Exchange, I get these values...

```
Dim Message = vClient.Inbox.GetMessage(vItems(i).UniqueId)
Dim vSubject As String = Message.Subject
Dim vBody As String = Message.HtmlBody
```

The Return Receipt is not in the body, but can be seen at the end of the full message. What I need to do is get a handle on one, if it exists - and then I can get the text to add it to the body and prefix the Subject with 'Read:'

The second question is how exchange is dealing with read receipts for the InBox messages.

When the message(s) is/are downloaded from Exchange with IMAP it finishes with

```
vClient.Inbox.AddFlags(vItems(i).UniqueId, MessageFlags.Deleted, True)
```

To delete from the server (I have the messages locally, no need to keep them) and then...

vClient.Inbox.Expunge()

As soon as Expunge is run Exchange immediately sends a 'Not read' reply. How do I overcome that behaviour? I don't want to set the flags to 'Read' first as they haven't.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

============= UPDATE======================

I have tried to get the read receipt as described...

```
'Check if the item is a return receipt
Dim report = TryCast(Message.Body, MultipartReport)
If report IsNot Nothing AndAlso report.ReportType.Equals("disposition-notification", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) Then
vBody += report.ToString
vSubject = "Read: " & vSubject
End If
```

After adding this I emailed a message - when it was opened a read receipt was returned but it passed over the code.

=========FURTHER UPDATE==========

If a message contains a read request, I can see that in the Disposition-Notification...

```
Disposition-Notification-To: "My Name"[MyName@MyDomain.net]
```

So, I guess I can handle that in the Client in a similar way to Notes Client.

What I am really interested in is the read report sent back when the message I send out is opened. When it comes back this is appended to the end of the message without Disposition_Notification

```
MIME-Version: 1.0

Return Receipt
                                                                       
Your       Testing for read request                                     
document:                                                               
                                                                       
was        "Some Name" [SomeName@SomeDomain.net]             
received                                                                
by:                                                                     
                                                        
         
at:        03/01/2024 08:10:32
```

For some reason this is not in the body of the message, and I think doing a search for 'Read Receipt' might only work for some servers/clients as they tend to give it different names and some DO send it as part of the body as well...

```
report-type=disposition-notification
Content-Language: en-US

--_000_ab934b08b0a54e928bb127db7b8c5277domainnamecouk_
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
     
boundary="_002_ab934b08b0a54e928bb127db7b8c5277domainnamecouk_"

--_002_ab934b08b0a54e928bb127db7b8c5277domainnamecouk_
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"

Your message

To: Kate Smith
Subject: Submission query 
Sent: Thursday, January 18, 2024 1:07:03 PM (UTC+00:00) Dublin, 
Edinburg=
h, Lisbon, London

 was read on Friday, March 1, 2024 12:12:08 PM (UTC+00:00) Dublin, 
Edinburg=
h, Lisbon, London.

--_002_ab934b08b0a54e928bb127db7b8c5277DDomainName_
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Type: text/html; charset="us-ascii"

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv=3D"Content-Type" content=3D"text/html; 
 charset=3Dus-ascii"=
 >
 <meta name=3D"Generator" content=3D"Microsoft Exchange Server">
 <!-- converted from text --><style><!-- .EmailQuote { margin-left: 1pt; pad=
 ding-left: 4pt; border-left: #800000 2px solid; } --></style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <font size=3D"2"><span style=3D"font-size:11pt;">
 <div class=3D"PlainText">Your message <br>
 <br>
 &nbsp;&nbsp; To: Kate Smith<br>
 &nbsp;&nbsp; Subject: Submission query 
 on<br>
 &nbsp;&nbsp; Sent: Thursday, January 18, 2024 1:07:03 PM 
 (UTC+00:00) Dublin=
 , Edinburgh, Lisbon, London<br>
 <br>
 &nbsp;was read on Friday, March 1, 2024 12:12:08 PM (UTC+00:00) 
 Dublin, Edi=
 nburgh, Lisbon, London.</div>
 </span></font>
 </body>
 </html>
```

As for dealing with 'not read' reports, it looks like there is a way to turn them off at Exchange Online, but they keep updating the interface so many times the only method I can find is already out of date.

Answer (score 0):

This question is answered in the MailKit [FAQ](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/FAQ.md#smtp-process-read-receipt)

#### Q: How can I process a read receipt notification?

A read receipt notification comes in the form of a MIME message with a top-level MIME part with a MIME-type
of `multipart/report` that has a `report-type` parameter with a value of `disposition-notification`.

You could check for this in code like this:

```
var report = message.Body as MultipartReport;
if (report != null && report.ReportType.Equals ("disposition-notification", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
    // This is a read receipt notification.
}
```

The first part of the `multipart/report` will be a human-readable explanation of the notification.

The second part will have a MIME-type of `message/disposition-notification` and be represented by
a [MessageDispositionNotification](https://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/T_MimeKit_MessageDispositionNotification.htm).

This notification part will contain a list of header-like fields containing information about the
message that this notification is for such as the `Original-Message-Id`, `Original-Recipient`, etc.

```
var notification = report[1] as MessageDispositionNotification;
if (notification != null) {
    // Get the Message-Id of the message this notification is for...
    var messageId = notification.Fields["Original-Message-Id"];
}
```

For more information on this topic, read [rfc3798](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3798).

Comment: Please don't post answers that solely link to an external ressource

Comment: I have updated the question based on your answer (that I got from the link, which is fine by me) and I have added an upvote

Comment: I have updated the question again. Interested in identifying both read requests and read replies. Some send the read reply in the body, some do not - the ones that do not also don't include disposition-notification.